# Closing main from the child form in winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form A with a button called `btnA` and a datagrid.
When I click on this button, another form B opens which has a button btnB. When I click on btnB, I need to close form B and refresh form A. How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: for closing just this.Close(); i guess

Comment: @Mythje - this.Close() would make his entire app to close, if he started a Application.Run() in FormA, It'll be appropriate to use this.close() in formB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create `FormB`, pass a reference to `FormA`

```
class FormB : Form
{
    FormB(FormA parent)
    { 
        this.Parent = parent;
    }
    ...

    protected void btnB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       parent.RefreshGrid();
       this.Close();
    }
}
```

and then on butB click, you can close formB and access formA to refresh it.

Comment: A nice suggestion, however, to the tender minded, this might provoke plumbing that might lead one to the dreadful Cross Thread exception.

Comment: This is the method I'm using for my requirement for such scenarios. It works well. Try this. 

@Bala- Thanks bala

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ShowDialog()` in `FormA` to show `FormB`. This will show `FormB` modally. Then, when you close `FormB`, execution will continue in `FormA` on the statement after `ShowDialog()`. Write your refresh code there.

Comment: but note that form b will be modal in this case

Comment: I know. See @Bala R for how to pass references, but OP sounded like he was really only starting and IMO modal dialogs are easier to handle.